# Is there a way to show the keyboard after the row has been inserted?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uikit, first-responder

I have a tableview cell that has a textfield inside it.

I want it to become first responder after the row has been inserted. But there is no clear way to get a call back after the insertion is done?

I tried call becomeFirstResponder of the textField, in the cell's viewWilDisplay and that just froze the UI

Answer (score 0):

Try insert the rows with [batch update](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates). That function has completion block, so you can call the becomeFirstResponder from there.

Answer (score 0):

I know it little bit silly trick but helpful for me.

first make one tempObject to store int value of new row.
for example:

```
var insertCellIndex : Int = -1
```

In cellforIndex method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
            if self.insertCellIndex == indexPath.row
            {
              // make your textfield become first responder
            }
            else
            {
                print("nothing")
            }
}
```

with the help of button insert new row

```
@IBAction func btnApplyFilterClicked(_ sender: Any)
{
    self.arrTemp.append("test") // insert in array
    self.insertCellIndex = self.arrTemp.count - 1
    self.tblView.reloadData()
}
```